# Let $\gamma:[0, 2\pi ] \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Compute the integral $\int_{\overleftarrow{\gamma}} \dfrac{e^z}{z(z-4)} \ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $\gamma:[0, 2\pi ] \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Compute the integral $$\int_{\overleftarrow{\gamma}} \dfrac{e^z}{z(z-4)} \ dz$$

Defining $f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z}$ I can write $$\int_{\overleftarrow{\gamma}} \dfrac{e^z}{z(z-4)} \ dz= \int_{\overleftarrow{\gamma}} \dfrac{f(z)}{z-4} \ dz$$ and now we can use Cauchy's integral formula and obtain that $$\int_{\overleftarrow{\gamma}} \dfrac{e^z}{z(z-4)} \ dz = 2\pi i f(4) = \frac{2\pi i e^4}{4}.$$

I would like to verify the result, but I don't know how to compute the integral on mathematica. Am I using the formula in a correct manner?

Comment: you should set $f(z)=e^z/(z-4)$... then your integral will be $2i\pi f(0)$ ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not. The function $f$ is undefined at $0$, and therefore you cannot apply Cauchy's integral theorem. Furthermore, $4$ is outside the region of $\Bbb C$ bounded by the image of $\gamma$. But if instead you define $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-4}$, then you have$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{e^z}{z(z-4)}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi if(0)=-\frac{\pi i}2.$$

Comment: So you have to use Cauchy's integral theorem always on the singularity point?

Comment: No, but in this case it's the simplest approach.

Comment: @Werner No. That's not the point. Cauchy's integral formula is valid for holomorphic functions . The $f$ you have defined is not holomorphic. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Review the assumptions of Cauchy Integral formula thoroughly and ask yourself the following questions:-

is $f$ how you defined it holomorphic inside the circle $|z|=1$?

If not then should you have defined it to be $f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{z-4}$ ?

Is the function above holomorphic inside the unit disc?

If yes now can you apply Cauchy integral formula and conclude that $\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-0}\,dz = 2i\pi f(0) $ ? .

Alternatively you can use the Residue Thoerem and get that $\int_{\gamma}\frac{e^{z}}{z(z-4)}\,dz = 2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{e^{z}}{z(z-4)}$  .

Both methods should yield you the answer $\frac{-i\pi}{2}$